# Import a certificate on Linux

Tags: linux, certificate, import

I need help with importing a certificate on my Linux.
here is the status :

I have a linux Centos 6.4 server with Apache installed. On a windows server, i have BSF. This BSF is secured and in order to connect it, i need to open an https link  from my Linux
to the windows server
i have the *pfx file that i have generated on windows and copied to the Linux server.

Then i did some google, followed many explanations and got lost. https to the needed site still does not work..

thanks
karine

Comment: the link i am trying to open is  https://nim1611:62201/bsf/service/RecordingOperationFacade

Comment: What error do you get when trying to open the https site? What browser are you using? Is it sufficient if you import the certificate into your browser or do you need it system wide? And where did you copied the pfx file to?